# facebook sdk Insufficient permissions for sharing content via Api

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

In my app there is a basic photo editor, i'd like the users to share these photos to share to Facebook, AFAIK, Facebook Sharing doesn't require publish_actions approval. i use the share api like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = imageContainer.getDrawingCache();
        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(bitmap)
                .setCaption("Check my new photo")
                .build();
        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();
        ShareApi.share(content, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                Log.i("success", result.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {


            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.i("error", error.getMessage());

            }
```

i have configured the facebook content provider and everything else as mentioned in the Facebook developer website. but i keep getting this error  message **Insufficient permissions for sharing content via Api.** does anyone know what the issue is and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the code for a custom interface right now (`ShareApi.share`):

> If you want to use your own interface for sharing, you need to: ... Request the publish_actions permission when people log into your app

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Take a look at the docs, this may be what you need instead:

```
ShareDialog.show(activityOrFragment, content);
```

Comment: do i need publish_action permission even if there is no Facebook login function in the app? i'd just like to post image to my Facebook wall.

Comment: use ShareDialog.show, it should not need login/permissions. for ShareApi.share you do need login.

Comment: why the downvote? please add a comment if there is something wrong with my answer.

Comment: I'm using ShareDialog.show and was able to post thru the dialogue. However, there is no new post on my fb page. Do I need publish permission for successful sharing? I can't find sufficient documentation on this.

Comment: for an official dialog, you should not need any permission